# Float to Int type conversion in Python for large integers/numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, type-conversion, precision

Need some help on the below piece of code that I am working on. Why original number in "a" is different from "c" when it goes through a type conversion. Any way we can make "a" and "c" same when it goes through float -> int type conversion?

```
a = '46700000000987654321'
b = float(a)  => 4.670000000098765e+19
c = int(b)    => 46700000000987652096
a == c        => False
```

Comment: You need to think about why you are doing this.  If you need to do arithmetic, then perhaps you should keep it as an integer.  The Decimal type, suggested below, is very much slower than either int arithmetic or floating point arithmetic.  On the other hand, real-world cases where you need to keep more than 16 digits of prevision are very, very rare.

Answer (score 3):

Modified version of [my answer to another question (reasonably) duped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75247282/364696) to this one:

This happens because `46700000000987654321` is greater than the integer representational limits of a C `double` (which is what a Python `float` is implemented in terms of).

Typically, C `double`s are [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) 64 bit binary floating point values, which [means they have 53 bits of integer precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_and_interchange_formats) (the last consecutive integer values `float` can represent are `2 ** 53 - 1` followed by `2 ** 53`; it can't represent `2 ** 53 + 1`). Problem is, `46700000000987654321` requires 66 bits of integer precision to store (`(46700000000987654321).bit_length()` will provide this information). When a value is too large for the significand (the integer component) alone, the exponent component of the floating point value is used to scale a smaller integer value by powers of 2 to be *roughly* in the ballpark of the original value, but this means that the representable integers start to skip, first by 2 (as you require >53 bits), then by 4 (for >54 bits), then 8 (>55 bits), then 16 (>56 bits), etc., skipping twice as far between representable values for each additional bit of magnitude you have beyond 53 bits.

In your case, `46700000000987654321`, converted to `float`, has an integer value of `46700000000987652096` (as you noted), having lost precision in the low digits.

If you need arbitrarily precise base-10 floating point math, replace your use of `float` [with `decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) (conveniently, your initial value is already a string, so you don't risk loss of precision between how you type a `float` and the actual value stored); the default precision will handle these values, and you can increase it if you need larger values. If you do that (and convert `a` to an `int` for the comparison, since a `str` is never equal to *any* numeric type), you get the behavior you expected:

```
from decimal import Decimal as Dec, getcontext

a = "46700000000987654321"
b = Dec(a); print(b)  # => 46700000000987654321
c = int(b); print(c)  # => 46700000000987654321
print(int(a) == c)    # => True
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1chJTU5MzcxRyEztyC/qETBBcpNLAYxdRTSU0uS8/NKUitKuLgSFWwVlEzMzA2gwNLC3MzUxNjIUIkrCSgFVK@RqGmtUFCUmVeikaSpoKCsYGungE0DVzJQPUQVTH0yXvUQNSCcqKlga6sAUg1VH1JUmvr/PwA)

If you echo the `Decimal`s in an interactive interpreter instead of using `print`, you'd see `Decimal('46700000000987654321')` instead, which is the `repr` form of `Decimal`s, but it's numerically `46700000000987654321`, and if converted to `int`, or stringified via any method that doesn't use the `repr`, e.g. `print`, it displays as just `46700000000987654321`.

Answer (score 1):

Please read this document about **Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations** :

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

for your example:

```
from decimal import Decimal
a='46700000000987654321'

b=Decimal(a)

print(b)    #46700000000987654321

c=int(b)

print(c)    #46700000000987654321
```