# Why can the difference of different floating numbers be 0 in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, precision, largenumber

Why is the result of below code 0 in python3?

```
a = "4.15129406851375e+17"
a = float(a)
b = "415129406851375001"
b = float(b)
a-b
```

Comment: Floating-point error.

Comment: Having read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) what specifically did you expect as a different result?

Comment: @khelwood: That's not a great duplicate; it covers "Floating point math is in fact broken (for a certain definition of broken)", but the issues here are from exceeding the limits of `float` to represent integers, not an issue with precision to the right of the decimal (even if the two issues are related to some extent).

Comment: use the `decimal` built-in package to convert your strings into `decimal.Decimal`s then it will print the correct value of `-1`

Comment: Voted to reopen: feels like another case where the close-vote links to the general issue (which the OP may even be aware of), but a more precise answer is more appropriate here.

Comment: Thanks @kaya! [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/364696) is always a useful reference, just not a duplicate (the answers tangentially touch upon related information, without the detail), but I couldn't find the dupes specific to `float`s losing precision for large numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because both `415129406851375001` and `4.15129406851375e+17` are greater than the integer representational limits of a C `double` (which is what a Python `float` is implemented in terms of).

Typically, C `double`s are [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) 64 bit binary floating point values, which [means they have 53 bits of integer precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_and_interchange_formats) (the last consecutive integer values `float` can represent are `2 ** 53 - 1` followed by `2 ** 53`; it can't represent `2 ** 53 + 1`). Problem is, `415129406851375001` requires 59 bits of integer precision to store (`(415129406851375001).bit_length()` will provide this information). When a value is too large for the significand (the integer component) alone, the exponent component of the floating point value is used to scale a smaller integer value by powers of 2 to be *roughly* in the ballpark of the original value, but this means that the representable integers start to skip, first by 2 (as you require >53 bits), then by 4 (for >54 bits), then 8 (>55 bits), then 16 (>56 bits), etc., skipping twice as far between representable values for each bit of magnitude you have that can't be represented in 53 bits.

In your case, both numbers, converted to `float`, have an integer value of `415129406851374976` (`print(int(a), int(b))` will show you the true integer value; they're too large to have any fractional component), having lost precision in the low digits.

If you need arbitrarily precise base-10 floating point math, replace your use of `float` [with `decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) (conveniently, your values are already strings, so you don't risk loss of precision between how you type a `float` and the actual value stored); the default precision will handle these values, and you can increase it if you need larger values. If you do that, you get the behavior you expected:

```
from decimal import Decimal as Dec  # Import class with shorter name

a = "4.15129406851375e+17"
a = Dec(a)  # Convert to Decimal instead of float
b = "415129406851375001"
b = Dec(b)  # Ditto
print(a-b)
```

which outputs `-1`. If you echoed it in an interactive interpreter instead of using `print`, you'd see `Decimal('-1')`, which is the `repr` form of `Decimal`s, but it's numerically `-1`, and if converted to `int`, or stringified via any method that doesn't use the `repr`, e.g. `print`, it displays as just `-1`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1chJTU5MzcxRyEztyC/qETBBcpNLAYxubgSFWwVlEz0DE0NjSxNDMwsTA2NzU1TtQ3NlcBSQDUaiZpcSWBVqIoMDAyVwBIgNUmaXAVFmXklGom6SZr//wMA)